# How to format signedUserToken for sinch?

Tags: sinch

I'm trying to integrate Sinch into my ROR webapp, and am having some difficulty formatting the signedUserToken to start the sinchClient.
Here is my view, using haml :

```
#{@signedUserTicket}
%script{src: "//cdn.sinch.com/latest/sinch.min.js", type: "text/javascript"}
= javascript_tag do
    $(function(){
    $sinchClient = new SinchClient({
    applicationKey: 'APP_KEY',
    capabilities: {messaging: true, calling: true},
    supportActiveConnection: true,
    onLogMessage: function(message) {
    console.log(message);
    },
    });
    $sinchClient.start({
    'userTicket' : "#{@signedUserTicket}",
    });
    });
```

And whatever formatting I try to do in the controller, the closest I get to succeeding is :

```
DOMException [InvalidCharacterError: "String contains an invalid character"
code: 5
nsresult: 0x80530005
location: http://cdn.sinch.com/latest/sinch.min.js:5]
```

I'd appreciate a little help and would even build a Rubygem for integrating Sinch in Rails if I get the right info and can spare some time.

Cheers,
James

Edit :

I have tried a few modifications and am getting closer (I think).
The problem of InvalidCharacter came from the trailing '='s which apparently don't decode well in Javascript.

My new controller is now :

```
class SinchController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def client
    username = current_user.username
    applicationKey = "APP_KEY"
    applicationSecret = "APP_SECRET_B64"
    userTicket = {
        "identity" => {"type" => "username", "endpoint" => username},
        "expiresIn" => 3600,
        "applicationKey" => applicationKey,
        "created" => Time.now.utc.iso8601
    }
    userTicketJson = userTicket.to_json
    userTicketBase64 = Base64.strict_encode64(userTicketJson).chop
    digest = Digest::HMAC.digest(Base64.decode64(applicationSecret), userTicketJson, Digest::SHA256)
    signature = Base64.strict_encode64(digest).chop
    @signedUserTicket = (userTicketBase64 + ':' + signature).remove('=')
  end
end
```

But now I'm facing the following error:

> POST https://api.sinch.com/v1/instance 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   client:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.sinch.com/v1/instance. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http:// localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

(the space before localhost is due to new user restrictions on SO)

I added Rack::Cors to my rails server to try and allow Cross-domain requests in case it came from my own requests, but whatever configuration I tried, it seems the request never contains the right headers.
Am I misunderstanding CORS requests? Does the problem come from the requests generated by sinch.min.js?

Regards,
James

Comment: Don't forget to remove your app key and secret from your post!

Comment: If you used one of the solutions below, please mark that answer as accepted! Or, if you had a different solution, please share that.

Answer (score 2):

Error message is due to Firefox base64 decoder can't decode the token, due to symbols (such as @) that are not in the base64 character set. This suggest that the ticket is actually not passed to start(), and this line may be incorrect;

```
'userTicket' : "#{@signedUserTicket}",
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know HAML but shouldnt 
  'userTicket' : "#{@signedUserTicket}",
be   'userTicket' : @signedUserTicket,

Comment: I tried all sorts of combinations around this haml issue and have sticked to my original formatting, the only one which doesn't throw back an invalid character (the character sometimes being ':' or '&').